# How to show custom html page on specific errors with Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

Frequently, whenever we deploy, our servers will return 503s for up to 2-3 minutes as assets are compiled. How is it possible with Express/Node to serve a static html page if the server code comes back 503? Surely there must be an easy way to listen for specific error codes?

Comment: Is your node process running? Is it behind a proxy?

Comment: @elmigranto Yes, it's behind a proxy

Comment: So you want an HTML shown when your node process is down? That depends on proxy itself and how it handles upstream errors. It's nothing specific to node/express/etc. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @elmigranto that's what I read too, so I don't think you're missing something.

Answer (score 2):

`app.use` [an error handler](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) as your last middleware:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.statusCode === 503)
    return res.render('errors/503.jade');

  next(); // default Express' error handler.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Copied the format directly from Express js Page.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

        app.use(bodyParser());
        app.use(methodOverride());
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

if (res.status === 503)
{
res.sendFile('yourfilepath/filename.html');
    }

});
```